# Bot(s) in SU Chat?

Tags: support, chat

What are the bots in the SU room? I see there's a new one with hangman and such, but what others ones are available? The ones that are in there, what commands do they accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's only one bot to my knowledge, [John Cavil](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/87560/john-cavil).

As his profile says, he's operated by [somequixotic](https://superuser.com/users/144607/somequixotic). Who is also responsible for some of the code behind it:

- https://github.com/allquixotic/so-chatbot-driver
- https://github.com/allquixotic/SO-ChatBot

Comment: What about poor Clippy! :(

Comment: The original chatbot is [here](https://github.com/Zirak/SO-Chatbot) written by [Zirak](http://stackoverflow.com/users/617762/zirak) who hangs out in the JavaScript room on [chat.stackoverflow.com](http://chat.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 0):

One of the bots has its documentation available [here on GitHub](https://github.com/Zirak/SO-ChatBot/wiki/Commands)